# Rewarded ad stops showing after several successful loadings

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob

In my game, I have 21 levels and at the start of each, rewarded and interstitial ads are loaded. However, after several successful loadings of rewarded ads, an error appears every time I try to load a new reward. Only restarting the game helps. There is no issue with using rewarded or interstitial ads separately. Implementation of loading and showing ads is almost the same as in the Google AdMob guide for Unity, except for my callbacks. Ads in AdMob and their IDs are set up correctly. What is the possible solution?

This is the error:
Rewarded ad failed to load an ad with error : {
"Code": 0,
"Message": "Internal error.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null",
"Response Info": {
"Response ID": "WqU7ZZCZBdCGjuwPgaKU-A8",
"Mediation Adapter Class Name": "",
"Adapter Responses": [
{
"Adapter": "com.google.ads.mediation.admob.AdMobAdapter",
"Latency": 60002,
"Ad Source Name": "AdMob Network",
"Ad Source ID": "5450213213286189855",
"Ad Source Instance Name": "AdMob (default)",
"Ad Source Instance ID": "",
"Credentials": {
"pubid": "ca-app-pub-8224242546412922/7598428652/cak=no_cache&cadc=66&caqid=WqU7Zar2A8PigAf2nr6gAw"
},
"Ad Error": {
"Code": 0,
"Message": "Internal error.",
"Domain": "com.google.android.gms.ads",
"Cause": "null"
}
}
],
"Response Extras": {
"mediation_group_name": "AdMob (default)"
}
}
}

--Monetization.AdMob.RewardedAdService:b__13_0(RewardedAd, LoadAdError)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:Exec()

I tried to use rewarded ads and interstitial ads separately and this works just fine. I also tried loading ads with delay but that did not help.

Comment: latency of 60002 sounds bad.